# How do I compare length of two strings of two struct members?

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I'm pretty much brand new to C.

I have a problem where I'm trying find the student with the longest name and delete them from my linked list. To do that, I need to compare the length of comp *name; for each member of the struct.

```
struct birthday{
    char *name;  
    ...
    struct list_head list;
};

LIST_HEAD(birthday_list);

int simple_init(void)
{
struct birthday *person;
    person = kmalloc(sizeof(*person), GFP_KERNEL);
    person->name = "Alicia";
INIT_LIST_HEAD(&person->list);

list_add_tail(&person->list, $birthday_list);

    person = kmalloc(sizeof(*person), GFP_KERNEL);
    person->name = "Ben";
INIT_LIST_HEAD(&person->list);

list_add_tail(&person->list, $birthday_list);
    person = kmalloc(sizeof(*person), GFP_KERNEL);
    person->name = "Dave";
INIT_LIST_HEAD(&person->list);

list_add_tail(&person->list, $birthday_list);
...
struct birthday *ptr;
list_for_each_entry(ptr, &birthday_list, list)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Name: %s\n",
    ptr->name);
}
}
```

What I'm looking for is to compare Alicia to Ben, store Alicia as the longer name, compare Alicia to Dave, and delete the Alicia node from the linked list. I have tried so many things to no avail. If anyone has

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you "have tried so many things" it would be best to show us these efforts. Then we can tell what went wrong. The code you show does not contain any code that tries to do what you ask.

Answer (score 0):

For string comparing, try `strlen()`.

`size_t strlen ( const char * str );`